# Can I get an hourly count including hours with no data?

Tags: mysql

I need a way of producing a report that shows the number of transactions (or taps) per hour. So far I have managed to get a table as below, but it skips out the hours with no data.

Is there a way I can have the hour shown even if the count is 0?

```
SELECT HOUR(`time`), Count(*)
FROM `taps`
WHERE DATE(`time`) = '2016-01-17' AND `readerid` IN 
            (SELECT `readerid` 
             FROM `readers` 
             WHERE `type` = 'A')
GROUP BY HOUR(`time`)
ORDER BY HOUR(`time`)
```

This produces the table below:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have *some* data for all hours, then you can phrase the query as a `left join` with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT HOUR(t.`time`), Count(r.readerid)
FROM tabs t left join
     readers r
     on r.readerid = t.readerid and r.type = 'A'
WHERE DATE(t.time) = '2016-01-17'
GROUP BY HOUR(t.time)
ORDER BY HOUR(t.time);
```

If this isn't true, then you need a list of hours, somehow.  One method is a subquery:

```
SELECT h.hr, Count(r.readerid)
FROM (select 0 as hr union all select 1 union all . . .
      select 23
     ) h left join
     tabs t
     on h.hr = hour(t.time) and
        DATE(t.time) = '2016-01-17' left join
     readers r
     on r.readerid = t.readerid and r.type = 'A'
GROUP BY h.hr
ORDER BY h.hr;
```

There are other ways to generate the list of hours as well.  The subquery is the most general.

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff! Subquery was the way for me there! One thing is the order in which they appear is dodgy due to the ordering. e.g 0, 1, 10, 11, 12 ..... 2, 20, 21, 22

Comment: @CallamThom . . . Somehow you have them declared as strings rather than integers.  As integers, they would sort correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

By using LEFT OUTER JOIN or RIGHT OUTER JOIN to the same table and aliasing it,  you can select the NULL values and even give them a value based on a condition stated in the query.

Please show your expected result in order to give a syntactic example.
And provide the tables you are using,  I tried to replicate but didn't find a way to establish a relationship between traps and readers.